# Whats the best way to handle a android listview that pulls paginated data when the data changes mid way

Tags: android, api, rest, android-listview, pagination

I am working on a Android app (and a IOS version) that pulls large amounts of jsom via a rest api and shows the items in listview

Because its large data, I have made the rest api do pagination in blocks of ten items and the listview pulls another ten items as the user scrolls through the list.

The web dataset changes daily and so I am wondering how to handle the scenario where:

1. the list gets page 1 items.
2. shortly after serving page 1, the web backend data set changes (new rows added/deleted).
3. Then the user scrolls, causing me to call for page 2, which gives me possibly different data (for example, their may not be a page 2, or page 1 items are now shifted to page 2, so we have duplicates).

If I cache the items in a local sqlite db, I can see the above scenario happening more if the user doesnt scroll to end of list immediately.

How can I handle this scenario gracefully?

Comment: maybe you need to get a ref from client (mobile) telling backend what was last record fetched, an ID maybe, so first time, mobile calls with `lastId= -1`, so backend gets top-10 or whatever qry you have there, on next page, mobile asks backed for data (next page) and `lastId=540`, so backend should get records which is higher than that ID, so no duplicates records will be returned, regarding the modified data, maybe you need to add arefresh button where client asks backend to return ALL records between min-id and max-id ...just some thoughts :)

Comment: So how does that work if the lastid passed to the web service has been deleted?

Comment: the lastId is not really needed by exact value, you just add a filter to the db-sql, asking for records `where row_id > lastId` beside other filters you already have, so even if already received records was updated, and your qry include some `order by modifiy_date desc` the `where row_id > lastId` will eliminate duplicates.

Comment: i can post this as answer with more details if u want

Comment: you know, it will not work, this may cause some records to be skipped, if a page had data with a row_id = 1200 which is that will cause next page to skip some rows, even if they were not received yet

Comment: Bummer. Back to the drawing board. I was thinking I could have a field called 'last updated'  and only update the list view If the Android client last updated matches the servers. But it will be bad ui experience

Comment: @DEzra did you manage to find an optimal solution to your problem ?

Comment: @pe60t0 not really, we decided the chance of duplicated items being shown on second page (if a item has been deleted) was acceptable as this was unlikely edge case scenario - no one has reported the scenario yet.

Comment: So you are just accessing the pages 1 by 1 regardless of new inserted/deleted data ?

Comment: Yes, the next set ( page of items) of json data is requested as the user scrolls down the list view (via onScroll()). The list view hasn't knowledge on whether dataset has changed. Gmail does this in a similar way as described in this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-dynamicaly